# Array element presence check quirks in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

When checking element presence in inline arrays via the `in` keyword, CoffeeScript ignores `indexOf` and rather does that many equality checks.

However, when referring to an array via a variable, it calls `indexOf` as expected.

**Input**

```coffee
foo = 1

# -----------
foo in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# -----------
bar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
foo in bar
```

**Output**

```js
var bar, foo,
  indexOf = [].indexOf;

foo = 1;

// -----------
foo === 1 || foo === 2 || foo === 3 || foo === 4 || foo === 5;

// -----------
bar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

indexOf.call(bar, foo) >= 0;
```

Demo code: [Link](https://coffeescript.org/#try:foo%20%3D%201%0A%0A%23%20-----------%0Afoo%20in%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%5D%0A%0A%23%20-----------%0Abar%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%5D%0Afoo%20in%20bar%0A)

I find this intriguing. Any ideas why?

Comment: Interesting quirk.
Might be intentional optimization where it's assumed if the array is hardcoded, it's not very long. Might be a bug.
I'd recommend asking this question in the repository: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/labels/question

Comment: Done - thanks for the suggestion: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/5392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this was an intended optimization to spare an array allocation.

From: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/5392